# numpy.ndarray has no attribute read (when trying to pass a video)

Tags: python, numpy, object-detection, video-processing, object-detection-api

I am attempting to write a video with annotations to a file ( or at least print it our on-screen while using google colab). I've tried using cv_imshow but this prints the video one frame at a time, which is not what I'm after. I've amended the script to use `VideoWriter`, but still getting stuck when using cap.read() as I am getting an error stating `numpy.ndarray has no attribute read`.

I understand why this error is occurring, as I believe the `.read()` function is expecting a video, while I am trying to pass a numpy array. However, I cannot seem to find another way around this. any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the full code I am using:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/vid1.mp4')
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np


while True:
    ret, image_np = cap.read()

    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0
                                         ].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,

          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    cap=image_np_with_detections

    
  
    res=(800,600)              # this format fail to play in Chrome/Win10/Colab
              # fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V') #codec
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264') #codec
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, res)

    while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
      ret, frame = cap.read()

      print("Frame number: " + str(counter))
      counter = counter+1
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    out.write(frame)

   

 out.release() 

 

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Track the value of `cap` carefully.  Yes `read` only works for an open file.  It should be obvious that if `cap` is already an array, you don't need to "read" it.  I see that `cap` is set before the loop, but also inside the loop.  Don't try fixes at "random"; make sure you understand the error, and what variable(s) is causing the problem.  Only then can you make a correct fix.

Comment: Hi hpaulj. Thank you for your input. I understand your comment and agree that cap should not be included in the loop as it is already referring to the file being read from the path provided prior to the loop. My (incorrect) attempt of including cap.read() inside the loop was to read the different frames so that out.write(frame) can make use of them. Do you happen to know how to adjust the code for this purpose, please?

Comment: The `read` docs talk abour grabbing the next frame.  So why change `cap` at all?  What's the point of `cap=image_np_with_detections`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to adjust the code in order to the VideoWriter to work. As hpaulj pointed out, I was assigning the variable cap twice.

The correct code is below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Workspace/Images/Test/vid3.mp4')
res=(800,600)            
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264') #codec
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/content/drive/MyDrive/Workspace/Images/Test/vid3output.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, res)

  while True:
    ret, image_np = cap.read()
    ##expand dimensions as the model expects images to have the shape :: [1,None, None,3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np_expanded, dtype=tf.float32)
    detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.5,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    out.write(cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections,(800,600)))

 
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```